# angular2 Adding two numbers view side

Tags: angular

I want to be able to add the numbers from two textbox:

```
template: `
    <h1>Adding inputBox Numbers</h1>
    <p>Num1: <input [(ngModel)]="num1"></p>
    <p>Num2: <input [(ngModel)]="num2"></p>
    <p>The sum is: {{ num1 + num2 }}</p> `
```

[image]

Even if I defined both variables as numbers:

```
export class AppComponent {
    num1 : number;
    num2 : number; 
}
```

So if I perform this operation the result is OK

```
 <p>The sum is: {{ 1 + 1 }}</p>
```

Result: 2

but if I use variables it preforms a concat so the result would be 11.

```
 <p>The sum is: {{ num1 + num2 }}</p>
```

result:11

Comment: The things written inside your input tag are strings not numbers.

Comment: yes, do you know anyway to convert or format them to numbers?

Comment: D. Simon's answer is partially correct actually. You can define a parseInt method inside your component. I will edit it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try this,

**`One way`**

```
 <h1>Adding inputBox Numbers</h1>
    <p>Num1: <input [(ngModel)]="num1"></p>
    <p>Num2: <input [(ngModel)]="num2"></p>
 <p>{{ num1*1   +num2*1 }}</p>
```

**[DEMO](http://%20%3Ch1%3EAdding%20inputBox%20Numbers%3C/h1%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3ENum1:%20%3Cinput%20[(ngModel)]=%22num1%22%3E%3C/p%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3ENum2:%20%3Cinput%20[(ngModel)]=%22num2%22%3E%3C/p%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3E%7B%7B%20num1*1%20%20%20+num2*1%20%7D%7D%3C/p%3E)**

**`2ND way`**

Create a function that will conver the String to a Number inside the ts file

```
ConvertToInt(val){
  return parseInt(val);
}
```

then call it

```
  <h1>Adding inputBox Numbers</h1>
    <p>Num1: <input [(ngModel)]="num1"></p>
    <p>Num2: <input [(ngModel)]="num2"></p>
   <p>{{ ConvertToInt(num1)   + ConvertToInt(num2) }}</p>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/MV3tXcCux4q88MRrn2r5?p=preview)**

Comment: I have added both ways, you just need to convert it to an integer. when you multiply by 1 it becomes an integer

Comment: second way it ok but I was avoiding functions, anyway Im taking note of it

Answer (score 5):

Models from HTML inputs are always in string format. You can use this workaround:

```
<p>The sum is: {{ (num1-0) + (num2-0) }}</p>
```

Comment: I have tried this way before But I get no results, I am doing this on a Angular PlayGround, do you think it is related to that?

Comment: $scope isn't AngularJs ? think in Angular 2 $Scope isn't exist anymore. Also Controllers isn't exist anymore...

Comment: it doesn't because your response is about AngularJs or Angular1. Which doesn't apply to Angular2.

Comment: @AleGarcia current response is working on AngularJS as well as on Angular 2+

Answer (score 5):

This is working for me:

```
<p>The sum is: {{ +num1 + +num2 }}</p>
```

Comment: This is perfect, Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just use type="number"

```
<h1>Adding inputBox Numbers</h1>
<p>Num1: <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="num1" ></p>
<p>Num2: <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="num2"></p>
<p>The sum is: {{ num1  + num2 }}</p>
```

Here is [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/TOnpXDr1S0QV0QkfuWpC?p=preview)

Following are some more way to achieve this

1. **Via Controller**:

   angular.controller('numCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
       $scope.num = parseInt(num , 10);  });
2. **Custom Filter** :

   ```
    app.filter('num', function() {

   return function (input) {

     return parseInt(input, 10);

   }});
   {{ (num1 | num) + (num2 | num) } }
   ```
3. **Expression**:

   //Declare below code in your controller:

   $scope.parseInt = parseInt;

   Then:

   {{parseInt(num1)+parseInt(num2)}}
4. **raina77ow**

   {{(num1-0) + (num2-0)}}

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ +element.num1 + +element.num2}}
```

Just add plus(+) before variable name...

Answer (score 0):

Add bracket.. Something like this..

```
<p>The sum is: {{ (num1 + num2) }}</p>
```