# convert string to number angular 2 one way binding

Tags: angular, angular2-template

convert the string to number angular 2 one way binding

```
[longitude]="loc.location.lng">
```

loc.location.lng is string i need to convert them to number.but still not working as I expect.
In interpolation it's working but in this not working.
Thanks

Comment: Actually what is working what is not working? and what you tried?

Comment: Hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482593/angular2-adding-two-numbers-view-side/45483501#45483501

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a function which convert the value to float as its location and return the value.

```
    ConvertString(value){
return parseFloat(value)
}
```

Call the function in template

```
[longitude]="ConvertString(loc.location.lng)"
```

Comment: Unlikely that it would work with the typo `Covert` <=> `Convert`. I'm also not sure what the `[longitude]={...}` syntax does. What is the meaning of the curly brackets? And you're missing a right paren. Finally, is it really that much trouble to properly format and indent your code?

Comment: Updated u can check it was typo mistake

Comment: Do not use this approach, use a custom pipe instead. You should never use function calls in Angular template [Why you should never use function calls in Angular template expressions](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496#:~:text=To%20avoid%20issues%2C%20it%20is,pipe's%20input%20does%20not%20change)

Answer (score 10):

You could also force the cast by trying this:

```
[longitude]="+loc.location.lng"
```

Comment: What about it if  the value of `loc.location.lng` is null?

Answer (score 3):

adii's answer is not good in terms of performance since change detection will cause the method to run several times .. consider using a pipe.