# Angular 2 way number binding converting to string from input

Tags: javascript, angular

Any time I enter a number into an input that is 2 way bound to my object the value is converted to a string.
**How can I force it or convert it to be a number?**

It seems like it should be very simple and yet I have struggled to find an elegant solution.

I saw this solution of using a function to convert it but I don't see how that would work for 2 way data binding.
[convert string to number angular 2 one way binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45860349/convert-string-to-number-angular-2-one-way-binding)

```
          <div class="row"> 
            <mat-form-field class="custom-control">
              <input type="number" matInput class="custom-control" [(ngModel)]="mpv.baseFare" required placeholder="Base Fare">
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          <div class="row"> 
            <mat-form-field class="custom-control">
              <input type="number" matInput class="custom-control" [(ngModel)]="mpv.mileageRate" required placeholder="Mileage Rate">
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
```

mpv is an object of class VehicleType I have my VehicleType class set up as follows.  The number types are completely ignored, I guess because it is at run time so just non typed javascript.

```
 export class VehicleType {
    baseFare: number;
    mileageRate: number;
}
```

UPDATE - CURRENT HACKY SOLUTION:

```
onSave(vehicleType: VehicleType) {
// Hack to convert string to number
vehicleType.bags = +vehicleType.bags;
vehicleType.baseFare = +vehicleType.baseFare;
vehicleType.mileageRate = +vehicleType.mileageRate;
vehicleType.passengers = +vehicleType.passengers;
this.vehicleTypeService.updateVehicleType(vehicleType.id, vehicleType).subscribe(result => {
```

Comment: How do you know it is being converted to a string?

Comment: It seems to work out of the box in this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hkjr6v ?

Comment: It is definitely being converted to a string.  I checked the type and it ends up in my firestore database as a string.

Comment: @Zze It appears to work with a normal input but fails with a angular material one as per my example.

Comment: Figured it.  See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the order of the attributes on a matInput mater.  This issue does not occur on a standard input only a matInput.

Does not work:

```
 <input type="number" matInput class="custom-control" [(ngModel)]="mpv.baseFare" required placeholder="Base Fare">
```

Works:

```
 <input matInput type="number" class="custom-control" [(ngModel)]="mpv.baseFare" required placeholder="Base Fare">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to modify the value when ngModel sets a new value then you're most likely looking at creating a get and set function. Example,

```
<div class="row"> 
  <mat-form-field class="custom-control">
    <input type="number" matInput class="custom-control" [(ngModel)]="baseFare" required placeholder="Base Fare">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="row"> 
  <mat-form-field class="custom-control">
    <input type="number" matInput class="custom-control" [(ngModel)]="mileageRate" required placeholder="Mileage Rate">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

get baseFare(): number {
  return mpv.baseFare;
}
set baseFare(value: any) {
  mpv.baseFare = pareseInt(value, 10);
}
get mileageRate(): number {
  return mpv.mileageRate;
}
set mileageRate(value: any) {
  mpv.mileageRate = pareseInt(value, 10);
}
```

That should do the job.

**Update:** you could just have value as any or both as any since you know the return type will be a number.

Comment: Error: 'get' and 'set' accessor must have the same type.

Comment: I found the answer. No need to change the class. See below.  Thanks though.